# nothing is being displayed in my gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

Hi nothing is being displayed in my gridview when i try this:

```
   protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FirstName = TextBox2.Text;
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT FirstName, SecondName FROM User WHERE FirstName LIKE '%" + FirstName + "%'";

        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

my sqldatasource is bound to a odbc connection string so I can connect to a mysql database
asp:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ODBCDataConnectionString %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ODBCDataConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT FirstName, SecondName FROM User WHERE FirstName LIKE '%' + @qsFirstName + '%'">
        <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="qsFirstName" QueryStringField="firstname" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        EnableModelValidation="True">
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: If you're using a parameterized query in your markup, why are you changing it to a concatenated query in the code?  (And in the process introducing a SQL injection vulnerability.)

Comment: because with sqldatasource for mysql i dont think you cant get params im not sure how to do the querystring for it

Comment: is there a way to set TextBox1.Text to QueryStringParameter = qsFirstName?

Comment: I'm not sure about the declarative markup-based widgets, I don't really use those.  But you should definitely be able to use a parameter in the SQL statement.  I believe the MySQL syntax for a parameter is to prepend it with a `?` rather than a `@`.  (That's one of the main reasons I don't use those widgets... A change to the DBMS requires a change to the UI markup.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of the select command after you build it?

SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT FirstName, SecondName FROM User WHERE FirstName LIKE '%" + FirstName + "%'";

Does FirstName have any trailing spaces?